# How to deal with a variable Likert scale in excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I have a column project and another with its components. The number of components is not fixed and each component has an importance level. I want to calculate percentage of each component based on how important it is. Percentage is calculated by (importance level of component/(sum of importance level of all components of that project)*100).
I don't know how to find out the number of component dynamically. I'm able to do it using VBA and wanted to know whether any functionality existed in Excel only

Comment: share some sample data, and how you want it to look after, the it sounds like this could be do-able if we could visualise your data

Comment: You can find the number of individual components if they have individual identifiers by using COUNTIF()

Comment: Better post the Sample data,, along with any Formula if you have tried,,,I'll try to crack it.

Answer (score 0):

As the comments suggest, more specific information would be very helpful.

But, if your data resembles the table below, a formula similar to this one will do what you ask.  It calculates the percentage of the total importance for each component of each project.

`=100*C2/SUMIF(A$2:A$17,A2,C$2:C$17)`

That formula was filled down from D2 in the table below.

[image]

I hope this helps.  If it doesn't solve your problem, please **edit** your question to provide a more complete explanation of what you're trying to do.

You can upload a screenshot of your data (and/or your expected results) to a sharing site such as imgur.com, and put the link to the picture in your edited question. Use the "link" icon at the top. Good luck.